# Modify HTMLCollection to return all innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to use my HTMLCollection to strip out the tags of the elements which it contains, for example, given the html:

```
<p><span>Hello, <i>world!</i></span> Some more text</p>
```

I would like to return

```
<p>Hello, <i>world!</i> Some more text</p>
```

At the minute I search for span tags in my html which returns an HTMLCollection, which seemed to be the easiest way for me to obtain all span tags, how can i use this collection to strip the tags completely and retain all innerhtml?

```
    $scope.modifyHtml = function (html) { 
        var el = document.createElement('div');
        el.innerHTML = html;

        var spans = el.getElementsByTagName('span');

        //Remove these spans from el but keep their inner!

        return el.innerHTML;
    }
```

Comment: `$('p').find('span').contents().unwrap();` will unwrap any span contents

Comment: @A.Wolff - sounds like an answer ?

Comment: @adeneo I'm not sure, it sounds like OP is using angularJS, not sure he is using jQuery (not jqLite)

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks man yeah this is what I was after, and yes I am using JQuery :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since tagged with jQuery

```
$scope.modifyHtml = function (html) {
    var $tmp = $('<div />', {
        html: html
    });

    //remove span elements    
    $tmp.find('span').contents().unwrap();

    return $tmp.html()
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q5rsx0n6/)

---

Without jQuery

```
$scope.modifyHtml = function (html) {
    var el = document.createElement('div'),
        spans, span, len;
    el.innerHTML = html;

    spans = el.getElementsByTagName('span'), span;

    for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
        span = spans[i];
        len = span.childNodes.length;
        for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            span.parentNode.insertBefore(span.childNodes[0], span)
        }
        span.parentNode.removeChild(span);
    }

    return el.innerHTML;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q5rsx0n6/4/), [Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q5rsx0n6/5/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, is there any chance you could tell me how to limit my search to only spans with a particular background-color as an inline style property?